VBA script running slow
I'm new to VBA and have written a script (admittedly with the support of ChatGPT). The script works exactly as intended, but is very slow. It takes about 15 mins to complete, overheats my laptop and pretty much freezes everything until it's done. I imagine the reason that it is so slow is due to the number of loops, but I'm not sure how to be less dependent on them.
The main goal of the script is to recognise codes in worksheets 'Budget','Revolut' and 'Abacus' associated with transactions in the format FFCxxx-BCxxx-BIxxx, decode them and correctly assign the budget item, budget category, cost-center and department. It then compiles the 'Revolut' and 'Abacus' worksheets into a new worksheet called 'combined', and cuts out transactions belonging to budget category 'Personnel', and pastes them into a new worksheet labeled as such.
How can I make the following code more efficient?
Sub InterpretCodeAndCombineData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim code As String
    Dim budgetItem As String
    Dim costCenter As String
    Dim budgetCategory As String
    Dim department As String
    
    ' Define your mappings for cost centers, budget categories, and budget items using Collections
    Dim costCenterMap As Collection
    Set costCenterMap = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Populate cost center mappings (based on full CCFxxx or CCPxxx code)
    costCenterMap.Add "Biophotonics", "CCF101"
    costCenterMap.Add "Optics & Photonics", "CCF102"
    costCenterMap.Add "Electronics", "CCF103"
    costCenterMap.Add "System integration", "CCF104"
    costCenterMap.Add "Biomedical", "CCF105"
    costCenterMap.Add "R&D initiatives", "CCF106"
    costCenterMap.Add "SMLE", "CCF107"
    costCenterMap.Add "Quality", "CCF108"
    costCenterMap.Add "Supply chain & manufacturing", "CCF109"
    costCenterMap.Add "Finance", "CCF201"
    costCenterMap.Add "Legal", "CCF202"
    costCenterMap.Add "HR", "CCF203"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim budgetCategoryMap As Collection
    Set budgetCategoryMap = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Populate budget category mappings (based on BCxxx)
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "External services", "BC001"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Travel", "BC002"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Consumables", "BC003"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Equipment (non-IT)", "BC004"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "IT Equipment", "BC005"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Software", "BC006"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Infrastructure", "BC007"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Training & team building", "BC008"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Personnel", "BC998"
    budgetCategoryMap.Add "Other", "BC999"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim budgetItemMap As Collection
    Set budgetItemMap = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Populate budget item mappings (based on BIxxx)
    budgetItemMap.Add "Salaries", "BI001"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Accounting", "BI002"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Audit", "BI003"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Legal", "BI004"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Certifications", "BI005"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Clinical trial", "BI006"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Contractors", "BI007"
    budgetItemMap.Add "Other", "BI999"
    On Error GoTo 0
  
     ' List of worksheets to process
    Dim sheetNames As Variant
    sheetNames = Array("Revolut", "Abacus", "Budget")
    
    ' Loop through each sheet
    For Each sheetName In sheetNames
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        
        ' Determine the last row with data in column B
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Loop through each row to interpret the code
        For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the first row is a header row
            code = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            
            ' Check if code is valid and contains "-"
            If Len(code) > 0 And InStr(code, "-") > 0 Then
                ' Parse the code
                Dim parts() As String
                parts = Split(code, "-")
                
                ' Ensure there are three parts to the code
                If UBound(parts) = 2 Then
                    ' Trim parts and convert to uppercase for case-insensitive matching
                    parts(0) = UCase(Trim(parts(0)))
                    parts(1) = UCase(Trim(parts(1)))
                    parts(2) = UCase(Trim(parts(2)))
                    
                    ' Get cost center from full CCFxxx or CCPxxx code
                    If ExistsInCollection(costCenterMap, parts(0)) Then
                        costCenter = costCenterMap(parts(0))
                    Else
                        costCenter = "Unknown Cost Center"
                    End If
                    
                    ' Get budget category from BCxxx
                    If ExistsInCollection(budgetCategoryMap, parts(1)) Then
                        budgetCategory = budgetCategoryMap(parts(1))
                    Else
                        budgetCategory = "Unknown Category"
                    End If
                    
                    ' Get budget item from BIxxx
                    If ExistsInCollection(budgetItemMap, parts(2)) Then
                        budgetItem = budgetItemMap(parts(2))
                    Else
                        budgetItem = "Unknown Item"
                    End If
                    
                    ' Output to worksheet
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = budgetItem
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = budgetCategory
                    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = costCenter
                    
                    ' Assign department based on cost center
                    Select Case costCenter
                        Case "Biophotonics", "Optics & Photonics", "Electronics"
                            department = "R&D"
                        Case "Finance", "Legal", "HR"
                            department = "S&O"
                        Case Else
                            department = "Unknown Department"
                    End Select
                    
                    ' Output department
                    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = department
                Else
                    ' If the code format is incorrect, mark as invalid
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Invalid Code"
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Invalid Code"
                    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = "Invalid Code"
                    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Invalid Code"
                End If
            Else
                ' If the code is invalid or doesn't contain "-", handle it appropriately
                ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Invalid Code"
                ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Invalid Code"
                ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = "Invalid Code"
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Invalid Code"
            End If
        Next i
    Next sheetName
    
   
    Dim wsRevolut As Worksheet
    Dim wsAbacus As Worksheet
    Dim wsCombined As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowRevolut As Long
    Dim lastRowAbacus As Long
    Dim lastRowCombined As Long

    ' Set references to worksheets
    Set wsRevolut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revolut")
    Set wsAbacus = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abacus")
    Set wsCombined = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")

    ' Clear existing data in Combined sheet
    wsCombined.Cells.Clear

    ' Copy headers to Combined sheet
    wsRevolut.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsCombined.Rows(1)

    ' Find last row in Revolut and Abacus sheets
    lastRowRevolut = wsRevolut.Cells(wsRevolut.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowAbacus = wsAbacus.Cells(wsAbacus.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Copy data from Revolut sheet to Combined sheet
    wsRevolut.Rows("2:" & lastRowRevolut).Copy Destination:=wsCombined.Cells(2, 1)

    ' Find last row in Combined sheet after copying Revolut data
    lastRowCombined = wsCombined.Cells(wsCombined.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Copy data from Abacus sheet to Combined sheet
    wsAbacus.Rows("2:" & lastRowAbacus).Copy Destination:=wsCombined.Cells(lastRowCombined + 1, 1)


    ' Step: Move rows with "Personnel" budget category to "Personnel" worksheet
    Dim wsPersonnel As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowPersonnel As Long
    Dim rngToMove As Range
    
    ' Set reference to the "Personnel" sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsPersonnel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Personnel")
    If wsPersonnel Is Nothing Then
        ' If the sheet doesn't exist, create it
        Set wsPersonnel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        wsPersonnel.Name = "Personnel"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Find last row in Combined and Personnel sheets
    lastRowCombined = wsCombined.Cells(wsCombined.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowPersonnel = wsPersonnel.Cells(wsPersonnel.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through "New - Combined" and move rows with "Personnel" category
    For i = lastRowCombined To 2 Step -1 ' Start from last row to avoid skipping rows after deletion
        If wsCombined.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Personnel" Then ' Assuming budget category is in column 4 (D)
            ' Find the next available row in "Personnel"
            lastRowPersonnel = wsPersonnel.Cells(wsPersonnel.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' Copy the entire row to "Personnel"
            wsCombined.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsPersonnel.Rows(lastRowPersonnel)
            ' Delete the row from "Combined"
            wsCombined.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i


MsgBox "Abacus and Revolut data has been decoded and compiled into Combined worksheet"

End Sub


' Helper function to check if an item exists in a Collection
Function ExistsInCollection(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ExistsInCollection = Not IsEmpty(col(key))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Working code belongs  on the sister site: CodeReview.  Using arrays instead of iterating over the cells will make the code 50-100 times faster or more.

So good script! Winter is coming :-)

I don't have any problem with posting working code to this site if there's still something which needs to be fixed,  "too slow to be usable" is one of those things.

Have you timed the various parts of your code to find out where it's slow?

...I would guess it might be the row deletions which are causing the slowness.  How many rows of data do you typically have, and what proportion of those rows get deleted and moved to wsPersonnel?

One last question: what exact version of Excel do you have (File > Account > Product Information if you're using Office 365)  Seems like a recent update caused some issues with VBA performance.

You could avoid your last loop entirely by using an AutoFilter - this would enable you to copy all visible rows in one step and then delete them all, also in one step.

I've played around with it for a while but would like to test the improvements. Could you share your file? If not publicly, you could send it to the email on my profile page.

This section of code should speed things up considerably:
' Determine the last row with data in column B
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    dim shtData as variant
    shtData = ws.range("B2").resize(lastRow,6).value
    ' Loop through each row to interpret the code
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the first row is a header row
        code = shtData (i, 1)

By reading all the data into an Array you can then loop through it in RAM instead of reading 1 cell at a time.
We can then update the additional columns in the array in RAM, instead of writing back to the sheet one-by-one
 shtData(i,3) = budgetItem ' ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = budgetItem
 shtData(i,4) = budgetCategory 'ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = budgetCategory
 shtData(i,5) = costCenter 'ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = costCenter

Once you're done processing, and just before you move to the next sheet, write the whole array back to the sheet (technically here, we're over-writing the values which are already there, but it was easier to provide the sample code this way than to create another array to store only the output values)
    ws.range("B2").resize(lastRow,6).value = shtData 
Next sheetName

